# is there a way to retrieve enum values using Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, enums, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

On ZF2, i'm trying to retrieve possible enum values using Doctrine 2.

tried to run 2 different queries but no luck:

1. SHOW COLUMNS FROM `{$table}` LIKE " . $column
2. SELECT COLUMN_TYPE

   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDatabase'

   AND TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'

   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'YourEnum'

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html

Comment: thanks @cptnk, already been there but couldnt find what i was looking for. maybe ill rephrase:
i need a method in doctrine 2 to retrieve the enum values from an alredy existing table/column

Comment: string should do the job then.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://knpbundles.com/

One of the most rated bundles is http://knpbundles.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle
Have a look

Comment: Anyway if you want to use Enum type you should add new DBAL type enum. Check http://knpbundles.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle code - https://github.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle/blob/master/DBAL/Types/AbstractEnumType.php